# libmtp error: Could not send object info. "Ubuntu 20.04"

Tags: 20.04

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

When trying to copy to a sd card on tablet I get this error "libmtp error:  Could not send object info.
I plug in a usb sd card reader and it cant see it. Used Gparted. Nothing. Checked lsusb through terminal and also nothing.
I tried front and back usb's, unplugged all other usb's, plugged it into powered external usb docking station still nothing. Cant see it in reader but cant copy to it in tablet.

Any ideas?

Comment: OS Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Comment: You can always click the [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1252882/edit) button to extend your question. No need for comments ;-)